# SCSS, Sass and other CSS preprocessor support for code snippets

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

Add a possibility to run SCSS, Sass and other CSS preprocessors (LESS, Stylus, PostCSS, maybe others) in code snippets. Many developers use CSS preprocessors. This will remove need to convert demos to plain CSS and/or adding links to third-party sites which support this (like CodePen) just to demonstrate code examples.

### CSS Preprocessors and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Some people downvoted this suggestion because they think that this will encourage people to post non-minimal examples. I don't agree with this.

Violation of MCVE is caused by people not able or not willing to localize a problem. Anybody can post tons of HTML/CSS/Javascript (regardless of preprocessor usage) or even just link to his development site and ask something link "plz help, it's not working". I'm sure most of us saw a lot of question like this. And I don't see any connection between using CSS preprocessors and 
code minimalism.

Often people post pretty minimal Sass/SCSS because they are just using it. I know that I can edit question and translate Sass/SCSS to CSS or ask OP to do it. But I think this is really redundant action. If question is not MCVE, it should be closed/deleted/downvoted but lack of this possibility will encourage people to post links to sites like CodePen because our code snippet don't have many features.

Comment: Meh! Code snippets are overrated enough already. MCVE's is what we want.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What is contradiction between MCVE and SCSS/SASS support in code snippets?

Comment: Hidden implications are ...

Comment: There is a concern about people unnecessarily posting Sass/SCSS source code when the actual problems lie in the generated CSS. That'd mean an MCVE would have a shell of Sass around it, which is not so M. Wouldn't comments help here though?

Comment: @D-side Not always at all. Often people post pretty minimal Sass/SCSS because they are just using it. I know that I can edit question and translate Sass/SCSS to CSS or ask OP to do it. But I think this is really redundant action. If question is not MCVE, it will be closed/deleted/downvoted but lack of this possibility will encourage people to post links to sites like CodePen because our code snippet don't have many features.

Comment: This is exactly what I mean. However, as long as the problematic Sass/SCSS is in the question as well, links to external sandboxes are perfectly okay (like, we don't expect to have ideone built-in, right?). This makes the benefit of this feature rather... slim.